# Facebook authentication mechanism changed?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe, auth-token

My application is running within an IFrame and has been running fine for month. Since last week, the main page keeps refreshing because it looks lie the parameters auth_token and fb_sig_session_key are not provided to my iframe content anymore.

Has anything changed on the platform lately with that regard ?

Many thanks for your support.

Jonathan.

Comment: Are you still using the [Legacy Canvas Auth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig/)?

Comment: I guess... The application has been assembled a while ago. I heard about the new oauth mechanism, but I never heard that the legacy one would be deprecated...

Comment: I thought we deprecated all non-Oauth mechanisms last year and they were scheduled for cutoff in October 2011 - maybe some endpoints were missed at that time?

Comment: Well, I don't know why it suddenly stopped working for you, and I haven't used the "oldschool" auth for some time now. I haven't found anything about it in the [Change Log](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/changelog/) but it was a quick search, you might want to search better. In any case I strongly recommend to switch to the new auth.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Facebook Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/), you are only provided `oauth_token`along with some other data, but nothing that looks like fb_sig_session_key. Try looking through the tutorial on the signed request, as well as the [other authorization tutorials](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) on Facebook. They provide the most up to date information.

If you are still using the [Legacy Canvas Auth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/fb_sig/#migrate), you'll want to read the passage there about migrating. Instead of fb_sig_session_key, you should use `Use the oauth_token for all API calls.`